Recessed Ceiling Junction Box, too deep?
We had an existing box, which sat flush to the drywall, but it had broke on one side of the threading, causing the chandelier to pull down a little (probably not helped by our younger son going on the table and grabbing it). We decided to replace it with a beefer metal hanger, but it looks like the box is 3/8" recessed on one side, and pretty close to flush on the other. It's on a sloped ceiling. The lights metal bracket sits flush against the box, so no pressure on the drywall. And this box, it legit feels like it's screwed right to a joist.
So the question is, should we even worry or care about changing it? For that to happen we would need to remove the light and unscrew the bracket, flip it around, and bend the metal tabs on it up, and then try to manually set it so it's flush.
For reference, this is the bracket that was put in this time:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-4-in-Round-1-1-2-in-Deep-15-3-cu-in-Metallic-Ceiling-Fan-Light-Fixture-Box-and-Brace-Kit-for-New-Work-CMB150-NB/205383182
Photos below are how it's currently installed:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/N6SSExs8aTWTvfz19
https://photos.app.goo.gl/cPDuw3ytmP3ZYxjF6
https://photos.app.goo.gl/4MkExWKHS2LAxT4t6

As long as it is mechanically secure and the cover looks good enough, there's no reason to try to level the box.  This is a perfectly fine installation -- you could probably swing from that.
Only exception would be if you put in a ceiling fan, and then you'd want it to be a bit more level.

Now I am thinking of the movie animal house.

Thanks! Have no plans to ever put a fan in there since it's the dining room, in a large open floor plan, living room close to it, and a fan there.
And yes, cover sits flush on the ceiling. Just had to lower the center bolt thing a little bit first for the fan. But looks great, and I have never seen this firm of a box, except out old house which had pancake boxes straight under the joist.

The box is fine.
Finish installing the trim and tell your son that because you had to pay for a new box, he can't have a new toy.
Ceiling boxes are not made for children to swing from.

New box, $10. In-law helped replaced it in the attic. So was not a huge deal. And obviously they are not made to swing on. But try telling a 2.5 year old to not do something lol
